# R HELP! CHANGING COMMAS WITH PERIODS

Tags: r

Here is my task:

There is some structual issues with this dataset, write a function, named `convert_number` that will accomplish the following:

1. change the numbers in a column so that the ',' is a '.'
2. convert that column to a double

:

```
convert_number <- function(data, col) {
countries[col] <- as.character(countries[col])
  countries[col] <- scan(text=countries[col], dec=",", sep=".") (countries[col] <- as.double())
}

convert_number("countries", "Net.migration")
```

I first did the following:

```
countries$Net.migration <- sub("^$", "0", countries$Net.migration)
```

in order to change all the blanks to "0"s so that I can switch out the comma, but I realize a question further down in my assignment asks the amount of NAs in a column so I can't have "0"s in those cells. I am guessing there is a better way to do it than `scan(text=...)`?

I'm a beginner (especially with functions) and I think I am overlooking a simpler way to do this.

Here is a sample:

```
tail(countries, 5)
```

I wrote this function:

```
convert_number <- function(x){
    x <- as.character(x)
    x <- gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".",x = x, fixed = TRUE)
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    return(x)
}
data$Coastline..coast.area.ratio <- convert_number(data$Coastline..coast.area.ratio)

   convert_number <- function(x){
    x <- as.character(x)
    x <- gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".",x = x, fixed = TRUE)
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    return(x)
}
data$Coastline..coast.area.ratio <- convert_number(data$Coastline..coast.area.ratio)
```

**IDK WHAT TO PUT IN X!!!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

I've made some test data, if it's not a good fit for your data you'll have to provide some.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat <- tibble(value = c("1,23", "3.546", "13", "8,234"))

mutate_at(dat, "value", ~as.numeric(str_replace(., ",", ".")))

>
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1  1.23
2  3.55
3 13   
4  8.23
```

if there are multiple columns that need to be cleaned, replace `"value"` with `c("value", "value2", "value3", "etc.")` in `mutate_at`.